# Customise CListCtrl MFC class (or custom draw it) to filter down to specific rows while maintaining selected/deselected state

Tags: listview, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC CListCtrl instance that often displays hundreds of rows (and possibly more in future). It is used for selecting data (LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES is used), or more typically to de-select a handful of exceptions to a broader rule. It would be very handy to be able to filter the rows displayed in the control down to those that match some search criteria, and display only a handful of rows, while the rest of the rows in the control remain temporarily hidden, but retaining their selected/de-selected status.

I can't see anything immediately within CListCtrl to support this. I originally imagined it could/should be able to be done with custom draw handlers... but it seems that all items must be erased in place, and painted in the same place - it is not possible (as far as I know) to erase the unfiltered items in one place, then repaint the filtered items in a different place to produce a condensed list.

Is this correct? Does it mean that in order to manage a filterable and selectable list of items, one cannot directly use the CListCtrl instance on its own to track the items states - one must keep a separate data structure with the item states in that instead? If that's the answer, I can manage that separate data structure OK, but I'm just surprised that such a common practice as filtering is not obviously supported in such a common type of control. If it is supported, can someone point to documentation/examples for it?

Comment: The simplest way to filter a list-view's displayed items is by using a virtual list view (see [How to Use Virtual List-View Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls)). Owner (or custom) drawing cannot be used to alter the number of items displayed.